# I am having an issue in acquiring the access token for BOX API

Tags: go

```
 {re, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    a := json.Unmarshal(re, &accessobj)}
```

Getting error like

> error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Comment: You're probably receiving html if it's finding a '<' instead of a json value. Have you tried printing the response out and looking at it?

Answer (score 0):

The error

> error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Means that `json.Unmarshal()` tried to parse the content you passed to it *assuming* json format but it found a `'<'` character where it shouldn't have. As suggested, your input is *not* in json format, most likely an HTML document.

Take a look at this code:

```
re := []byte("<html></html>")
var accessobj struct{ X string }
a := json.Unmarshal(re, &accessobj)
```

In this example the content *is* HTML. Try to run it (on [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/x9-XKCgzJa)) and you get identical error message:

> invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value